# How Does One Make a Sitemap for a Flex Website?

Tags: sitemap

I've got a Flex website and I'm not sure how to make a sitemap for it. For a standard HTML page, sitemaps are straight forward. As Flex sites use a "pageless" architecture, I'm not sure what I should do. If anyone has any suggestions, please let me know.

UPDATE:

As I understand it, Google doesn't look at anything after the # in a URL. So in a deeplinked Flex site, Google wouldn't see the second page-- where it reads view=12 in the sample sitemap below.

Or does Google handle sitemaps differently? Should I go ahead and make a sitemap with all of the deeplinked URLS: http://brainpinata.com/#view=12, http://brainpinata.com/#view=4, etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <url>
      <loc>http://www.brainpinata.com/</loc>
      <lastmod>2010-12-01</lastmod>
      <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
      <priority>1.0</priority>
   </url>

   <url>
      <loc>http://brainpinata.com/#view=12</loc>
      <lastmod>2010-12-01</lastmod>
      <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
      <priority>1.0</priority>
   </url>
</urlset>
```

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are referring to the same site as in your previous question it looks like you only have 7 or 8 pages. Since your site is Flex you can't use an online sitemap generator, so you will have to do the XML by hand (which isn't hard). I would take a look at this article:
http://sitemaps.org/protocol.php

Comment: Hi Adam, Thank you for the message. Yeah, I've posted a few questions all about my site www.brainpinata.com. Thanks for the link. As I understand it, Google doesn't look at anything after the # in a URL. So in a deeplinked Flex site, Google wouldn't see the second page. I updated my question to make it a little more clear. Wht are your thoughts? Thank you.